# My footer, changes it parent

Tags: html, css, model-view-controller, footer

I have a mvc project, and in it I have one layout page that contains a Header, RenderBody(), and a footer, and some scripts. Like this:

```
<body class="main">
  <div class="header">...</div>
  @RenderBody()
  <div class="footer">...</div>
</body>
```

And I have a page with this layout that contains two partials. like this:

```
@model Entity.Models.Photo
@{
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_mainLayout.cshtml";
 }
<div class="upPage">

   <div id="upPhoto">
      @Html.Partial("~/Views/_upPhotoContainer.cshtml", Model)
   </div>

   @Html.Partial("~/Views/_uploadBox.cshtml")
</div>
```

The problem is when I run the project, in browser the footer part will make itself as a child of the div with class 'upPage'. But its in the layout page and not related to this page. I could not find any problem with CSS or my code. Its driving me crazy. I've done many things but none of them worked...

Comment: Do your `</div>`s in the output page add up to one for every `<div>`? From what I can see here it looks like something you're including might not have closed all divs it opened, 'cause that would cause this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I checked it again and nothing was wrong from closing divs. 'Clearfix' solved my problem... :)

Comment: Ohhhh I was thinking it was a DOM-child, not a visual child. Haha, I misunderstood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that everything you are including is properly closed, then I can only think of this using a clearfix, which usually helps me with misplaced elements when adding them through PHP. Might help you too:

```
@model Entity.Models.Photo
@{
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_mainLayout.cshtml";
 }
<div class="upPage">

   <div id="upPhoto">
      @Html.Partial("~/Views/_upPhotoContainer.cshtml", Model)
   </div>

   @Html.Partial("~/Views/_uploadBox.cshtml")

   <!-- HERE -->
   <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  .clear{
      clear: both;
      height: 0px;
   }
```

Comment: oh, Thaannkssss... it worked... it is a really crazy problem :|.   Thank you again :)